# Onedrive can't upload folders or empty files

Tags: onedrive

I just tried to upload a VM virtual machine file to Microsoft sky drive and got the error:

```
Sorry Onedrive can't upload folders or empty files.
```

The file isn't empty! It's 6 GB. What's going on?

Comment: Are some of the files or directories empty?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem  and [this solution worked for me given  at Microsoft online support help thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-files/sorry-skydrive-cant-upload-folders-or-empty-files/ff152c2b-be4a-4c79-8bce-8169d5c23304)

Follow the steps

1. Close all Internet Explorer or Windows Explorer windows that are
   open
2. Open IE
3. Go to internet options
4. Click the Advanced tab, then click Reset
5. Select Delete personal settings check box *if you would like to remove browsing history, search providers, Accelerators, home pages, and InPrivate Filtering data*.
6. Click Reset In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box
7. When Internet Explorer finishes applying default settings, Click
   close then click OK
8. Close IE
9. Start OneDrive client and try to Sign-in again

Let me know if it works for you